# How to map array inside of Object in Redux React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I'm using React and redux-toolkit for front-end development.
When I try to map() the array inside of the object whole screen goes blank.
This is the data structure that I'm getting from the redux state.
[data structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAY7T.png)
This is the screen where I have call the state from the redux store:

```
const { id } = useParams();
  const { mocktest, isLoading, isError, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.mocktest
  );
  console.log(mocktest);
useEffect(() => {
    if (isError) {
      toast.error(message);
    }
    dispatch(getMockTestById(id));
  }, [isError, message, dispatch, id]);
```

This is my slice:

```
export const getMockTestById = createAsyncThunk(
  'mocktest/getMockTestById',
  async (id, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      // const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await mockTestServices.getMockTestById(id);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) 
        error.message 
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

This is how I'm trying to map() or access the data:

```
{mocktest.questionSet.map((qSet) => (
                    <h4 className="text-center">{qSet.setName}</h4>
                  ))}
```

This is what I was expecting setName to be displayed in h4 tag
I have also tried adding this.props.

Here is the  [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/heuristic-hooks-rswuie?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) of given scenarios

Comment: Add a line `<pre>{JSON.stringify(mocktest, null, 2)</pre>` and check what's the content of `pre` element.

Comment: It shows all the data that fetched from the backend via redux and axios

Comment: It's look like your initial state is undefined and the page just crashed. Try to check the value of mocktest in that component and if value is undefined, add some checks there

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique
The initial state of mocktest has all the required data.
After mapping like this all page goes white
{mocktest.questionSet.map((qSet) => (
   <h4 className="text-center">{qSet.setName}</h4>
 ))}

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for your code so someone can help you to find that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have missed the optional chaining before map function as it validates whether array you are mapping is invalid or not.

```
    {mocktest?.questionSet?.map((qSet) => (
                  <div key={qSet._id} id="body">
```

Comment: This answer is correct - but this is not a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator); this is [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)